# Django translation - makemessages commenting out entries

Tags: python, django, translation, jinja2

I am adding entries from .jinja templates to the django.po file for translation, and when I add the entries and reload the page the translations run fine.

However, when I run makemessages my new entries get commented out. Any ideas?

This is similar to the following, but since that hasn't been active in a year I was wondering if anyone has had any progress/new ideas:

[How to properly add entries for computed values to the django internationalization messages file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625991/how-to-properly-add-entries-for-computed-values-to-the-django-internationalizati)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, my .jinja templates weren't being included in the makemessages script. To enable them, you have to add `--extension=jinja` to the script.

I found answers telling me to run `python manage.py makemessages -e jinja`, but this did not work.