# How to translate variables inside a for loop in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in array %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to translate the `item` variable, I've tried using the `trans` tag like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in array %}
        <li>{% trans item %}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But Django complains with a syntax error stating that it was expecting an `empty` or an `endfor`

Comment: @RahulGupta Ooops! Yeah, I didn't had that tag, now it doesn't throw a syntax error but still not works, maybe it's because I had defined the value on a dummy function as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7625991/3107765) with a context and I have not provided one on the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **add `{% load i18n %}` at the top of your template** to use the [`trans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) tag.

From the docs on [internationalization:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code)

> To give your template access to these tags, put `{% load i18n %}`
>   toward the top of your template.